# Making a check in form with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a simple check-in site for my soccer team.
My site is http://www.labombafootball.com
Basically I made a list of players on my team with a simple 'IN/OUT' button for players to check-in if they are available.

Here's the horrible code I wrote so far, feel free to laugh.

```css
.height2 {
 height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
}
.height {
 height: 100px;
}
.fc {
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
body {
 font-family: monospace;
 font-size: 4em;
 font-weight: bold;
}
button {
 background-color: red;
}
button:focus {
 background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>La Bomba FC</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 height"><img class="fc" src="images/la-bomba-fc-sm.jpg"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#2 STEVE B</div>
    <button>
    <div class="col-xs-4">IN/OUT</div>
    </button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#1 INDER JHOOTY</div>
    <button>
    <div class="col-xs-4">IN/OUT</div>
    </button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#21 CHRIS NAKATSU</div>
    <button>
    <div class="col-xs-4">IN/OUT</div>
    </button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#88 NICK MARSHALL</div>
    <button>
    <div class="col-xs-4">IN/OUT</div>
    </button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#99 TONY YUN</div>
    <button>
    <div class="col-xs-4">IN/OUT</div>
    </button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#6 DANIELE BORRELLI</div>
    <button>
    <div class="col-xs-4">IN/OUT</div>
    </button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#11 NITESH SHETTY</div>
    <button>
    <div class="col-xs-4">IN/OUT</div>
    </button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#45 UDAYA MADANAYAKE</div>
    <button>
    <div class="col-xs-4">IN/OUT</div>
    </button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#9 ADRIAN PARTYKA</div>
    <button>
    <div class="col-xs-4">IN/OUT</div>
    </button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#5 PATRICK REGAN</div>
    <button>
    <div class="col-xs-4">IN/OUT</div>
    </button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#13 RAMEZ ALAM</div>
    <button>
    <div class="col-xs-4">IN/OUT</div>
    </button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#8 FAIZAN ALAM</div>
    <button>
    <div class="col-xs-4">IN/OUT</div>
    </button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#33 DAVID CLEBAN</div>
    <button>
    <div class="col-xs-4">IN/OUT</div>
    </button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#14 VICTOR JIMENEZ</div>
    <button>
    <div class="col-xs-4">IN/OUT</div>
    </button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#7 HARRY SANDHU</div>
    <button>
    <div class="col-xs-4">IN/OUT</div>
    </button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#77 JOHN PINEDA</div>
    <button>
    <div class="col-xs-4">IN/OUT</div>
    </button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#44 DEVON CARNEY</div>
    <button>
    <div class="col-xs-4">IN/OUT</div>
    </button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#? JUSTIN CONSTANTINEAU</div>
    <button>
    <div class="col-xs-4">IN/OUT</div>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me how I can save the value after the button is clicked?

Comment: have you got access to an SQL database on a server that you can save the data to? or should this just be saved locally to the device (in the case this was displayed in a locker room/reception)? you're probably best having a look at a JS ajax approach, if you're new to this, perhaps consider a helper tool like `jQuery`

Comment: I have access to an SQL database. Could you please point me to the right jQuery script because I'm the equivalent of a 1 year old, I can walk but I fall on my face alot. :)

Comment: so which value do you want?whether they have checked in or not that is IN or OUT?

Comment: Yes basically I want the default value to be OUT but when they click on it I want them to be able to toggle the value between IN and OUT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we update your html slightly to include the `playerId` in the button, we have something to identify the person on the server. Given you're using bootstrap already, i thought it best to use some bootstrap colours. Similarly, putting block elements (`div`) inside your `button`s is generally not a good thing, so have shifted the html around a tad.

This code uses [jQuery's ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function to `POST` data to your server. If this is your first play with jQuery, i can recommend getting your head around some [best practices and things like IIFE's](http://gregfranko.com/blog/jquery-best-practices/)

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/L1446bnn/3/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#2 STEVE B</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-xl btn-player-checkin" data-player-id="2">Check In</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
(function($, window, document) {
    $(function() {
        // bind to the click event of the checkin button
        $('.btn-player-checkin').on('click', function(){
            // if the button has the success class - assume the user is checked in
            var isCheckedIn = $(this).hasClass('btn-success');
            // get the player id from the data attribute
            var playerId = $(this).data('player-id');


            // call the send function
            // sendDataToServer(!isCheckedIn, playerId, $(this)); // send the status we want the player to save (ie. opposite of current);

            // if you would like to test the success function without the ajax call, comment out above and uncomment below
            if(!isCheckedIn){ // trying to check out
                $(this).text('Check In');
            }else{ // checking in
                $(this).text('Check Out');
            }
            // cycle classes
            $(this).toggleClass('btn-success btn-danger');

        });

        function sendDataToServer(newStatus, playerId, button){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://myfakeserver.com/checkin', // replace this with the url of the server end point
                method: 'POST',
                data: {playerId: playerId, status: newStatus} // send this data, on the server you could also record the timestamp of when this occurred
            }).done(function(){ // if we successfully complete the post
                if(newStatus){ // checking in
                    button.text('Check Out');
                }else{ // trying to check out
                    button.text('Check In');
                }
                // cycle classes
                button.toggleClass('btn-success btn-danger');
            }).fail(function(){
                // do something if the post fails
            });
        }
    });
}(window.jQuery, window, document));
```

PS. this may fall over given one of your players has an id of `?` currently

Comment: I uploaded your code to http://www.labombafootball.com but can you see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I did???<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: ah ok, you're not waiting until jQuery has finished loading, i have updated my code

Comment: Ok it works but when I reload the page the values aren't stored they reset?

Comment: @Majidiode, correct, you will need to `GET` them from the server and load them in, you asked for a point in the right direction with saving your check in/out data, this should be a good place to start, stackoverflow is not a place to have all the work done for you :)

Comment: @Majidiode, i have added a link to a jQuery best practices article that does something very similar to what you're looking to do :)

Comment: Thanks for your help haxxton, sorry I'm a super noob.

Comment: We all have to start somewhere, you've picked a good project to start on, with some good places to learn fundamentals. Take your time to get your head around things, there's plenty of great resources out there to help you complete what you're trying to do. If my solution was helpful to you, please consider marking it as the answer so others can find it when searching

Comment: I marked it as the answer but my rating is too low to show.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something as shown below in the code snippet ,where the button text changes according to whether it is currently IN or OUT.You can also get the value using the variable "inout"

```js
var divsclass=$(".col-xs-4");

    $.each( divsclass, function(elem) {
      console.log("element "+$(divsclass[elem]).html());
   $(divsclass[elem]).on("click",function(){
        var inout=$(divsclass[elem]).html();
   if($(divsclass[elem]).html()=="IN"){
   $(divsclass[elem]).html("OUT");
      $(divsclass[elem]).parent().attr('class','changeCol');
   }
        else{
          $(divsclass[elem]).html("IN");
          $(divsclass[elem]).parent().attr('class','changegreen');
}
   });
   
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <title>La Bomba FC</title>
        <style>
        .height2 {
          height: 50px;
          text-align: center;
        }

        .height {
          height: 100px;
        }

        .fc {
          display: block;
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;
        }

        body {
          font-family: monospace;
          font-size: 4em;
          font-weight: bold;
        }

        button {
          background-color: red;
        }
        .changeCol{
           background-color:blue;
}
          .changegreen{
           background-color:green;
}
        </style>

        <script>

        </script>

      </head>

      <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 height"><img class="fc" src="images/la-bomba-fc-sm.jpg"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#2 STEVE B</div>
            <button><div class="col-xs-4">IN</div></button>
          </div>
            <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#1 INDER JHOOTY</div>
            <button><div class="col-xs-4">IN</div></button>
          </div>
            <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#21 CHRIS NAKATSU</div>
            <button><div class="col-xs-4">IN</div></button>
          </div>
            <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#88 NICK MARSHALL</div>
            <button><div class="col-xs-4">IN</div></button>
          </div>
            <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#99 TONY YUN</div>
            <button><div class="col-xs-4">IN</div></button>
          </div>
            <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#6 DANIELE BORRELLI</div>
            <button><div class="col-xs-4">IN</div></button>
          </div>
            <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#11 NITESH SHETTY</div>
            <button><div class="col-xs-4">IN</div></button>
          </div>
            <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#45 UDAYA MADANAYAKE</div>
            <button><div class="col-xs-4">IN</div></button>
          </div>
            <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#9 ADRIAN PARTYKA</div>
            <button><div class="col-xs-4">IN</div></button>
          </div>
            <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#5 PATRICK REGAN</div>
            <button><div class="col-xs-4">IN</div></button>
          </div>
            <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#13 RAMEZ ALAM</div>
            <button><div class="col-xs-4">IN</div></button>
          </div>
            <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#8 FAIZAN ALAM</div>
            <button><div class="col-xs-4">IN</div></button>
          </div>
            <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#33 DAVID CLEBAN</div>
            <button><div class="col-xs-4">IN</div></button>
          </div>
            <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#14 VICTOR JIMENEZ</div>
            <button><div class="col-xs-4">IN</div></button>
          </div>
            <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#7 HARRY SANDHU</div>
            <button><div class="col-xs-4">IN</div></button>
          </div>
            <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#77 JOHN PINEDA</div>
            <button><div class="col-xs-4">IN</div></button>
          </div>
            <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#44 DEVON CARNEY</div>
            <button><div class="col-xs-4">IN</div></button>
          </div>
            <hr>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#? JUSTIN CONSTANTINEAU</div>
            <button><div class="col-xs-4">IN</div></button>
          </div>


        </div>
      </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the color of the button to change with the value change?

Comment: I have edited it to add a class depending on the text value ,so that the background -color of the button will change accordingly